# No module named 'Twisted'

Tags: python, pip, twisted

I just installed Python to start experimenting a bit with Scrapy. 
Found a tutorial to first install Miniconda and with this I was able to install Scrapy. Now the problem is that the software I'm trying to run also requires Twisted. So I installed twisted with pip.

Twisted seems to have been installed correctly but I'm still getting an error when running the script that the Twisted module could not be found.

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
================ RESTART: C:\xampp\htdocs\crawler\crawler.py ================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\crawler\crawler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\crawler\scrapy\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from twisted import version as _txv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twisted'
>>> 
================ RESTART: C:\xampp\htdocs\crawler\crawler.py ================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\crawler\crawler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\crawler\scrapy\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from twisted import version as _txv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twisted'
>>>
```

Anybody a suggestion?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This sometimes happens if you have more than one python versions installed. Do `which python` and make sure you're working on the same env

Comment: According the scrapy's official document, you shouldn't use `pip install scrapy` on windows, instead you should use `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`. (If you use the pypi one, you need to install Visual Studio C++ 14.0 compiler)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You installed **twisted** for python2. When you use the command `pip` , you are installing a package for python2. You are using python3 (3.6.3). To install **twisted** for python3, you have to do:

```
pip3 install twisted
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Seems to have fixed the issue. Is there also a catch like this in installing Cpickle? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, this works for all packages. If you are using python3, you should use `pip3 install packagename`. I suppose it would be the same for Cpickle.

Comment: Then I get the error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cpickle - No matching distribution found for Cpickle.

Comment: Do you know the latest version of cPickle?

Comment: From what I can find it think its cPickle 1.5

Comment: I believe it could work by doing: `pip3 install cpickle==1.5`

Comment: It reutns no matching distribution found.

Comment: cPickle is part of the standard library on Python 2.x.  It was renamed (_pickle) on Python 3.x to better reflect its intended nature (as an implementation detail for performance reasons).  If you have code that is trying to import cPickle, it is not Python 3.x compatible.

Comment: Maybe you can try: `pip3 install _pickle`

Answer (score 3):

To try if twisted correctly installed, start python interpreter and type

```
import twisted
```

If you can't import twisted, you should check if it is in your python path.
Python path can be checked in the python interpreter as

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

The directory, where your twisted is installed has to be among those folders.